# Spotify giving wrong value of current track (AppleScript)

Tags: applescript, spotify

I am currently trying to make an application that gets the duration of the current song playing in Spotify. To do this I am using AppleScript.

Here is my code:

```
tell application "Spotify"
    return the duration of the current track
end tell
```

The length of the song is 2.52 minutes, the code is telling me 172026 seconds.

By looking at the return value, it looks like it is returning the milliseconds and not the seconds of the track length. This I can fix easily by doing milliseconds*1000. The problem is 172026ms is not 2.52mins, instead it is 2.8671mins.

How am I meant to get the true value of the song duration?

Here is the Spotify AppleScript documentation:

> track n : A Spotify track.
>   duration (integer, r/o) : The length of the track in seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found that I needed to do a little bit of maths.

Here is the code:

```
tell application "Spotify"
    set tM to round (((duration of current track) / 1000) / 60) rounding down
    set tS to round (((duration of current track) / 1000) mod 60) rounding down
    set myTime to ((tM as text) & "," & tS as text)
    return myTime
end tell
```

Thanks to dronir for his code at https://github.com/dronir/SpotifyControl

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following code to read song & artist name (if you need it):

"inline": "if application \"Spotify\" is running then\rtell application \"Spotify\"\rreturn \" \" & (get artist of current track) & \" – \" & (get name of current track)\rend tell\rend if\rreturn \"\"\r"

(thanks to Toxblh from https://github.com/Toxblh/MTMR/blob/master/Resources/aadi_vs_anand.json)